# How to write complex syntax parser in flex/bison and connect it as vim plugin?

Tags: vim, bison, flex-lexer, vim-plugin

How to write complex syntax parser in flex/bison and connect it as vim plugin ?

Need some generic way to make vim colorer (and completion in ideal case) plugins using flex/bison -- especially for some complex languages, can't be covered by dumb vim regexps.

The same method should be used for Eclipse-like "outline" tab -- parse source and make clickable side panel for fast source navigation.

PS: win32 (mingw) .dll preferrably for this build: http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

Comment: Start your project and come back when you have actual programing-related questions that can actually be answered.

Comment: question actually was answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to do the actual parsing of a Vim buffer outside of Vim, by your flex/bison-based parser, and then perform the highlighting within Vim based on that parsing, right?

Well, inside Vim, the highlighting is based on regular expressions (given to the `:syntax match` or `:syntax region` commands). There's no way around that (short of extending Vim itself).

The only way that I see is using line / column addressing for parsed elements. Vim regular expression have special atoms that only match at a particular position (`:help /\%l`, `:help /\%v`).

In Vim 8, you could trigger your parser (asynchronously in the background) via the new `:help channel` feature.

#### Example

Your parser has identified an *identifier* at line 3, screen columns 14-16. You would synthesize the following Vim command:

```
:syntax match Identifier "\%3l\%>13v\%<17v."
```

#### Critique

This will work for static buffer contents. As soon as you're doing edits, highlighting will probably be trailing behind. Vim applies the regexp-based highlighting as you type, but your external parsing will add some more delay.

For complex syntaxes / large buffers, the number of distinct syntax elements may cause performance degradation within Vim. I'm not sure how efficient the regexp-based addressing is; this would need to be tested.